# How do I have an item in a WinForm ComboBox that the user cannot select?

Tags: .net, winforms

I have a combo box with a drop down style of ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList, as well as letting the user choose options it shows the current state.  So sometimes I wish it to show “unknown” but the user should never be able to choose “unknown” from the dropdown list.

Answer (score 1):

I guess most elegant would be to overload your `ComboBox`, and `ComboBoxItem`.

Add a property to the `ComboBoxItem` if it should be selectable or not, and on the `ComboBox` index changed event check the property and reject the selection if it shouldn't be selected.
It also enabled you to draw the nonselectable `ComboBoxItem` different, or give it a different font to make it clear to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I would set the DropDownStyle Property to DropDown and then just set the Text of the ComboCox to "unknow" (or an empty string).

You could check user input with the SelectedIndex Property (which should be -1, when the text is not corresponding from the list).